# a way to create blank picture without choosing any file on excel

Tags: python, excel

is there a way to create blank picture on excel? and without choose a picture from browse files. I wanna do this because i want to put a picture based on cell number. And i want to put it using python xlsxwriter. So basically I want to try with excel itself first. But i'm not finding any function that can put blank pictures. Thanks for any comment

Comment: Can't you just draw an empty or white rectangle?

Comment: already try it. but it's image format not picture format

Comment: "it's an image format" - your question is pretty unclear. Either you want to create a "blank image" without any file, then there is no give "picture format". Or you have already an image with a given format, then you have the picture as a file, in which case you *can* provide the filename to the `insert_image` function. Please clarify.

Comment: sorry i mean in excel it become drawing tools not picture tools

Answer (score 3):

How about using the [`worksheet.insert_image()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html) function?

Look at the home page at https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/ - there's an example of inserting an image into a cell right there, and a link to the code [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_demo.html#ex-demo). Just use a "blank" image file.

Or, if you are averse to using a file, you can supply image data in the optional parameter `image_data` which can be an [io.BytesIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object. See the documentation for `worksheet.insert_image()`.

**EDIT**

You can pass a URL to `insert_image()` in place of a file name. A file name is dervied from the URL, but it is not accessed, so you can use whatever you like, e.g. `http://localhost/blank.png`. Here's an example:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import xlsxwriter

image_data = BytesIO()
im = Image.new('RGB', (1,1), "white")    # blank image, dimensions 1x1, white background
im.save(image_data, 'PNG')

workbook  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('blank_image.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.insert_image('A1', 'http://localhost/blank.png', {'image_data': image_data})
workbook.close()
```

Comment: if use that function it must input the path file. can't input the formula

Comment: @lalalala: when you put the picture file directly in the folder of the script and deploy both together, you only have to know the file name of the image, not the "path", and there is no need to "browse to the path".

Comment: i mean i don't want to import any files. so it just "create" not "import" any files. If possible i mean

Comment: Then use the `image_data` optional parameter which contains the image data of a blank image, whatever that is.

Comment: can i put it like this?--->sheet3.insert_image('B2', {'image_data':  None})

Comment: but it still need a path

Comment: sheet3.insert_image('B2', 'blank.jpeg', {'image_data':  None})

Comment: i think its not possible to put it without file. so i'll just stick like this then. thanks for all of your reply

Comment: @lalalala - please see the documentation which clearly states that you still need to supply a file name, however, you can also supply a URL from which the file name is derived. The URL is not accessed, so it can be whatever you want, e.g. `http://localhost/blank.png` should do the trick. There is an example here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_images_bytesio.html#ex-images-bytesio

Comment: @lalalala - updated answer to demonstrate how it can be done without requiring an image file.